# Looking for the name of this function?

Tags: waves, terminology, computational-physics, mathematics

$$2\Delta\frac{\sin(2\pi\tilde{\nu}\Delta)}{2\pi\tilde{\nu}\Delta},$$
$\tilde{\nu}$ is wave number (1/cm), $\Delta$ some constant (no units).

Is this just a sinc function scaled by $2\Delta$, or does it have a specific name?

Comment: I mean, it's also $\sin (2 \pi \tilde{\nu} \Delta)$ scaled by $1/\pi \tilde{\nu}$.  It kind of depends on whether you're viewing it as a function of $\tilde{\nu}$ or of $\Delta$.

Comment: *”no units”* $\Delta$ needs to have units. How are you going to take the sine of some number of inverse centimeters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His name is George, please take good care of him.

If you are doing numerical computations and want a name for your computer library, `sin(x)/x` may have precision issues for $x≈0$ which a well-coded `sinc(x)` can avoid.

Naming this function "George" is a little silly, as at least one downvoter seems to have pointed out. However, if a function is included in a software library under its own name, that's a hint that there may be some computational issue which you would prefer not to discover by rolling your own version. The classic example is the hypotenuse function `hypot`, which has an overflow issue. Suppose you want `hypot(3e200,4e200) == 5e200`. The naïve computation $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ overflows, because `9e400` doesn't fit in a double-precision number.  But the equivalent $b\sqrt{1+(a/b)^2}$ does not overflow, and also has better accuracy when $a\ll b$.

The question of whether your function has a name is a reasonable question.

Comment: You know what, I'll take it

Comment: It might help if you clarify the relevance of the answer part of your answer. Right how, it is hard to identify the signal after the noise.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Good point.

Comment: Much better :)  Only the thing with the downvoter is no longer up to date.